# Prevent CSS conflicts in webapps

Tags: css

I am building a webapp which others may embed on their website. A part of this webapp constructs dialogues, which have their own stylesheets. A problem may occur if, for example, my dialogue container is in a class `.container`, while the website the app is embedded on also uses a `.container` for some other means.

I have considered renaming all my classes like `.appname-container`, and will do that if there is no other solution. However, I would like to be as lazy as possible. Is there any easier way to prevent unforeseen conflicts with stylesheets I have no control of?

**Edit**: My webapp wraps itself around a `<video>` element, so I'm not sure that `<iframe>`s can be used.

Comment: The best answer is in your question. I would follow the appname prefix technique exactly.

Answer (score 1):

iframes are the only way to avoid all conflicts with existing apps. Name-spacing your css is great to avoid causing styling elsewhere but without a frame, existing styles will likely impact your content. If your content is simple, you can likely get away with some resets

Comment: Can I generate the iframe on the fly and write the dialogue data into it rather than linking to an iframe on my server?

Comment: I don't know how customers would be embedding your content to begin, you can generate iframe elements but adding content without any actual source may not be possible. I know `about:blank` should work but I don't know how browsers would treat that as a document. It's best to generate the iframe or provide the iframe source for your customers and have it access a page on your end

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, we will eventually be able to use the CSS3 `all` property for this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be ready for use yet. (I couldn't find it mentioned at Caniuse yet.)